# How to get back to default color from selected country in amcharts

Tags: angular, typescript, amcharts

I have implemented map with `amcharts`. When I select(zoom) a particular country, filling it will color. Now when I want to reset the map size, not able to remove the fill color.

This is my code

```
this.polygonSeries.dataFields.zoomLevel = "zoomLevel";
this.polygonSeries.dataFields.zoomGeoPoint = "zoomGeoPoint";
var polygonTemplate = this.polygonSeries.mapPolygons.template;
var as = polygonTemplate.states.create("active");
as.properties.fill = am4core.color("#d8854f");
```

Code to zoomout map

```
public mapCountry_selected(country)
{
  var target=this.polygonSeries.getPolygonById(country.id);
  // Pre-zoom
  this.mapChart .zoomToMapObject(target);
    setTimeout(function() {
      target.isActive = true;
}, 1000);
}
```

Code to Reset map. This code is only setting map to normal position but not removing the selected color from `mapCountry_selected`

```
public ResetButton()
{
var polygonTemplate = this.polygonSeries.mapPolygons.template;
var as = polygonTemplate.states.create("active");
as.properties.fill = am4core.color("#d9d9d9"); //default color
this.mapChart.goHome()
}
```

How can I remove `fill` color to normal?

Answer (score 1):

set current active status in to default using `setState("default")`  then it works. i added codepen below when you clicked home button view will set in to default state.

[codepen for reset default](https://codepen.io/yesithGama/pen/OJMrKgQ?editors=1010)

you can refer this one also [amcharts states](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/tutorials/resetting-map-position-zoom/)